# Were Sgt. Preston's slightly-too-small sunglasses intended to be funny?

Tags: costume, vanishing-point-1997

[The 1997 made-for-TV movie "Vanishing Point"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120430/) (a remake of [the 1971 film of the same name](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067927/)) contains a car chase in which the protagonist, James "Jimmy" Kowalski, is pursued by Sergeant Charles "Chuck" Preston (the latter is accompanied by his reluctant colleague Gilmore). The sequence can be viewed on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONChzy1Aiw8).

During the chase, both Kowalski and Preston wear sunglasses. Kowalski's are unremarkable, but Preston's are slightly too small. Here's a comparison (Preston is on the right):

[image]

Given that the cost of sunglasses was presumably negligible compared to other expenses associated with the production of the movie, I assume the choice of sunglasses for both characters was deliberate. Preston's sunglasses appear to be Ray-Ban Aviators (or something similar), which aren't small by design (unlike some other types of sunglasses). Indeed, Kowalski's sunglasses are also aviator-style and are normally-proportioned relative to the size of his face.

Is it likely that the size of Preston's sunglasses was intended to be funny? A couple searches yielded nothing relevant, so it seems the creators of the movie haven't commented on this subject. The car chase sequence contains other elements that are clearly intended to be comedic (Gilmore's reactions, Preston's crude bumper sticker, etc.), but it's not clear to me if the size of Preston's sunglasses was supposed to act as a humorous visual metaphor for his insecurity or was simply reflecting some aspect of 90s fashion as it pertained to sunglasses with which I'm unfamiliar.

Comment: "*[...] but Preston's are slightly too small.*": opinion-based :) joke aside, they seem like pretty standard sunglasses. Depending on the brand, you'll find many of them this size, and it's just a question of personal choice I believe. What makes you think they're too small? (even *slightly*)

Comment: If you look at the zoom and framing of the shots pictured, and also compare the apparent steering wheel and headrest sizes, there's an alternate explanation: The actor who plays Preston just has a bigger or wider head, making the sunglasses look small by comparison. It's definitely true that telling how actually short, tall, skinny, or wide an actor is can be almost impossible by just watching them in films and TV. I still remember seeing Don Johnson in real life, and even though he seemed so tall and thin in *Miami Vice*, he is like 5'5" with very broad shoulders.

Comment: @OldPadawan *What makes you think they're too small?* There's a definitely an element of subjectivity here, but as they're aviator-style sunglasses, which are often distinguished by being fairly large relative to the size of the wearer's face (e.g., see [the results of an image search for "people wearing aviator sunglasses"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=people+wearing+aviator+sunglasses&source=lnms&tbm=isch)), I think most people would agree they're at least a bit on the small side.

Comment: @Todd-Wilcox *The actor who plays Preston just has a bigger or wider head, making the sunglasses look small by comparison.* I think you're right about Preston's actor (Steve Railsback) having a larger head, but surely the production team could have found larger sunglasses to accommodate it!

Comment: Could have, but perhaps didn’t.